# Remote Validation is Not Being Hit

Tags: remote-validation

I'm trying to use remote validation to make sure an input has a value but only when a previous input has a specific value. However, the remote validation is not being hit.

I have put a break point on the remote validation action in the controller and that is never hit.

This is in my model:

```
[Remote("_Validate_Show", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "Group_Id,Dev_Group_Id", ErrorMessage = "Please select an option")]
public bool? Show { get; set; }
```

This is my controller:

```
public class ValidationController
    {
        public JsonResult _Validate_Show(bool? Show, Guid? Group_Id, Guid Dev_Group_Id)
        {
            if (!Show.HasValue && Group_Id.HasValue && Group_Id == Dev_Group_Id)
            {
                return base.Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return base.Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

And this is what I have in my View:

```
<div>@Html.ExtendedDropDownListFor(model => model.Group_Id, Model.Group_Ids)</div>

<div>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Show, Model.Show_Options)</div>
<div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Show)</div>
```

Basically if the 'Group_Id' is the 'Dev_Group_Id' then 'Show' must have a value but if the 'Group_Id' is not the 'Dev_Group_Id' then 'Show' can be null.

I even tried to simplify it and remove the additional fields so it just checked the 'Show' value but again the action in the controller was never hit.

I can also confirm that I have these scripts in my view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using asp.net or asp.net-core?

Answer (score 0):

Your `_Validate_Show` is get only and remote validation uses post. Add `[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]` to the method viz:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
public JsonResult _Validate_Show(bool? Show, Guid? Group_Id, Guid Dev_Group_Id)
        {
            if (!Show.HasValue && Group_Id.HasValue && Group_Id == Dev_Group_Id)
            {
                return base.Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return base.Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've just tried this and no luck.